# ROS 2 encoder data how to collect and publish

Tags: odometry

I am working on building a mobile robot in ROS2 on the Jetson nano i have 2 i2c mini encoders that i can get their ticks using a python code and library. How would i go about publishing and processing this data so it can be used along side an IMU for the robots odometry.